# Is there a possibility to run a job in argocd after all the apps are deployed and are in sync

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

I want to trigger a workflow from argocd after all the apps are deployed and are in synced status. is there a way to monitor the deployment status of the apps and then trigger the job?

I have tried using post-sync-hooks, but looks like it works only for a single component, suppose I have 3 apps, I dont want to run post-sync-job all the 3 times, after all are deployed I need to trigger once. Please suggest on this.

Comment: "after all are deployed..." What does that even mean in the context of argocd? If you push changes to a single app and not the others, should your "global post-sync" job run? What if you update one app and then 30 minutes later update another app...when should that job run? It doesn't really make sense to talk about doing something "after all are edployed" because they can all be deployed at different times.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. There are post sync hooks.
See the documentation https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/resource_hooks/